# Security Config - configureGlobal

Tags: spring-session

Playing with Spring Session REST example, I'm curious is it possible to make the following flow:
1. In first time, an user passes its credentials, usename and password.
2. Spring Session will generate a token, puts it into Redis
3. Next time a user asks for some resources it passes its tiken.
My problem is that the following code is hardcoded:
`code
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }`
code`
How can I do it to be dynamic?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Session works independent of the security framework you choose, so the answer depends on which security framework you want to use. This means selecting the username / password for your users is totally independent of Spring Session.

Since the question is unrelated to Spring Session, you should consult the documentation of the security framework  you choose. In this instance, it is Spring Security so you can consult [Spring Security's documentation on authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication).

The first step is to determine how you want to authenticate.

For example, if you want to use JDBC authentication, you can use something like the following.

```java
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .withDefaultSchema()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

By default `jdbcAuthentication` expects that:

```sql
select username, password, enabled from users where username = ?
```

will return the username, the password, and if that user is enabled. You can customize this query if you like using properties on jdbcAuthentication(). See the javadoc for details.

**NOTE**: It is important to understand that `withDefaultSchema` and `withUser` are really only intended for in memory databases since it will try to add the schema and the user every time. In a production environment your users and schema should be added using other mechanisms (i.e. [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)).

The most flexible option is to implement a `UserDetailsService`. You can then look up users in any way you want. For example:

```java
@Service
public class UserRepositoryUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserRepositoryUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        MyUser user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user " + username);
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = convert(user.getRoles());
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
}
```

Then you can configure it using:

```java
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
    auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

You can find a [complete example of using a UserDetailsService](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-0-to-4.0/blob/dda960c125c4ef2cfb34f5bb8c9942ffc1b8b46f/src/main/java/sample/security/UserRepositoryUserDetailsService.java) in my [Spring Security 4 talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/spring-4-security).